# Capturar valor hidden em lopping

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Gostaria de ajuda sobre como pegar um valor de um `hidden` que esta em um util. Preciso desse valor para enviar para a próxima tela, mas como ele esta em uma tabela com vários linhas, eu não estou conseguindo fazer isso.
Preciso pegar esse valor no javascript.

A tela:

```
<div class="grupoLista">
   <util:tabela id="lista" colecao="${form.listaPrograma12}" paginar="true" indiceProperty="lerDe" totalRegistrosProperty="qtdTotalLista" tamanhoPagina="30" idxLinha="true">
   <util:coluna id="id" titulo="" propriedade="nuContrato" tipo="radio">
      <input type="radio"     name="listaIndice"          value="${idxLinha}" />
      <input type="hidden"    name="listanuContrato"      value="${lista.nuContrato}" />
      <input type="hidden"    name="listanuStatus"        value="${lista.nuStatus}" />
      <input type="hidden"    name="listanoStatus"        value="${lista.noStatus}"/>
      <input type="hidden"    name="listanoEmpresa"       value="${lista.noEmpresa}"/>
      <input type="hidden"    name="listanoGestor"        value="${lista.noGestor}"/>
      <input type="hidden"    name="listadtAssina"        value="${lista.dtAssina}"/>
      <input type="hidden"    name="listavlContrato"      value="${lista.vlContrato}"/>
      <input type="hidden"    name="listavlDevolucao"     value="${lista.vlDevolucao}"/>
      <input type="hidden"    name="listavlDev"   value="${lista.vlDev}"/>
      <input type="hidden"    name="listanuEstagio"       value="${lista.nuEstagio}"/>
      <input type="hidden"    name="listanoEstagioCont"   value="${lista.noEstagio}"/>
   </util:coluna>
</div>
```

O js

```
function listar(){
    var validado = true;
    if(!checkRadio()){
        mensagemAlerta("Selecione uma das opções na lista.", "INF");
        validado = false;
    }
    if(validado){
        var linSel = $("input[name=listaIndice]:checked").val();
        document.getElementById("nuContrato").value = $("#listanuContrato" + linSel).val();
        document.getElementById("nuStatus").value = $("#listanuStatus" + linSel).val();

        var idEstagio = $("input[name=listanuEstagio]" + linSel).val();
        document.getElementById("selEstagioCont").value = idEstagio;

        var noEstagio = $("input[name=listanoEstagioCont]").val();
        document.getElementById("noSelEstagioCont").value = noEstagio;


        submitForm("listarContratoDevolucao");
    }

}
```

Resumindo: No jsp é montada uma lista, uma tabela com várias linhas e colunas também. Eu seleciono uma linha através de um radio e aciono o botão para enviar o que selecionei. Eu preciso pega o campo listanuEstagio do que foi selecionado e jogar em outro hidden, pra quando acionar o botão enviar, esse valor permaneça para a próxima tela. A situação é: como capturar esse listanuEstagio já que ele faz parte de uma lista montada, com o código que fiz ele só esta retornando o valor da primeira linha.

*em tempo: estou fazendo apenas a manutenção do código.

**Segue código HTML:**

```
<html><head></head><body><div id="modalPane" style="visibility: hidden;"></div><div id="container"><div id="header"></div><div id="corpo"><div class="confidencialidade"></div>
      <!-- corpo -->
    <div id="funcao"></div><div class="divisor"></div><div style="float:left;float:right;"></div>
<form id="form" action="/projet/programa.do" method="post" name="ContratoForm">
<input id="breadCrumb" type="hidden" value="/projeto/programa.do?.....?mt=pesquisar;" name="breadCrumb">
</input><input id="backPage" type="hidden" value="/projeto/programa.do?mt=ini" name="backPage"></input>
<input id="mt" type="hidden" value="pesquisar" name="mt">
</input><input id="nuContrato" type="hidden" value="9999999" name="nuContrato"></input><input id="chkFiltroNumCont" type="hidden" value="" name="chkFiltroNumContr"></input>
<input id="tela" type="hidden" value="lista" name="tela"></input><div id="conteudo"><div class="informacao">
      CNPJ:  
    <b></b></div><div class="informacao">
      Nome Contratante:  
    <b></b></div><div class="grupoLista"><script type="text/javascript"></script><input id="qtdTotalLista" type="hidden" value="31" name="qtdTotalLista"></input><div id="divIE" class="divlinhaTabela"><table id="tblIE" class="dados" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr class="azul">
<th></th><th nowrap="nowrap"></th><th nowrap="nowrap"></th><th nowrap="nowrap"></th><th nowrap="nowrap"></th><th nowrap="nowrap"></th><th nowrap="nowrap"></th><th nowrap="nowrap"></th><th nowrap="nowrap" style="text-align:right"></th><th nowrap="nowrap" style="text-align:right"></th><th nowrap="nowrap" style="text-align:right"></th></tr>
<tr class="branco">
<td><input type="radio" value="0" name="listaIndice"></input>
<input type="hidden" value="9999999" name="listanuOperacao"></input>
<input type="hidden" value="4" name="listanuSituacao"></input>
<input type="hidden" value="Contratada/Notificado" name="listanoSituacao"></input>
<input type="hidden" value="Contrantante" name="listanoContratado"></input>
<input type="hidden" value="Gestor" name="listanoGestor"></input>
<input type="hidden" value="19/02/2016" name="listadtAssina"></input>
<input type="hidden" value="0000000000010000.00" name="listaValor></input>
<input type="hidden" value="0000000000000000.00" name="listavlDev"></input>
<input type="hidden" value="0000000000000000.00" name="listavlCredito"></input>
<input type="hidden" value="4" name="listanuEstagio'0'"></input>
<input type="hidden" value="Notificado de TCE" name="listanoEstagioOper"></input></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap"></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap"></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap">

                    9999999 - 99

</td><td nowrap="nowrap">
      Contratada/Notificado
</td><td nowrap="nowrap"></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap"></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap">
      Contratante
    </td><td nowrap="nowrap"></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap"></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" style="text-align:right"></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" style="text-align:right"></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" style="text-align:right"></td>
</tbody>
</table>
</div><div class="paginacao"><div class="numeros"></div>
<div style="float:left;"></div></div>
<span class="total"></span>
<div class="grupoBotaoLista"><div class="divisor"></div>
<img class="botao" onclick="listar();" src="resources/_images/botoes/bt_listar.gif" alt=""></img>
<img class="botao" onclick="volta();" src="resources/_images/botoes/bt_voltar.gif" alt=""></img></div></div></div>
</form>
      <!-- mensagem -->
    </div><div id="rodape"></div></div><form id="idsp" method="post" action="#"></form></body></html>
```

Comment: Esses inputs e o radio estão dentro da mesma célula <TD> ou na mesma linha <TH>?

Comment: Eles estão na mesma linha, não postei o código todo, mas esse rádio fica em uma coluna e ss repete em várias linhas.

Comment: Já tentei: document.getElementById("").value = $("#listanuEstagio" + linSel).val(); mas ele não alimenta selEstagioCont, e quando peço pra exibir dá unidefined

Comment: Tentar pegar o valor com isso: `var idEstagio = $("input[value="+linSel+"]").closest("td").find("input[name=listanuEstagio]").val();`... se não funcionar, troque o `"td"`por `"th"` ou `"tr"`.

Comment: vou tentar ok. obrigada

Comment: fiz a alteração, mas ao executar na página, apareceu a mensagem: [13:08:05.499] TypeError: $(...).closest is not a function

Comment: Seu código possui muitos erros, por ex, este valor sem fechar as aspas: `name="listaValor` e esse valor aqui: `name="listanuEstagio'0'"`... esse `'0'` dentro no `name` está correto?

Comment: Essa foi uma tentativa para concatenar um valor pra eu reconhecer o número do estagio (tentativa frustrada). O código original estava assim : <input type="hidden" value="4" name="listanuEstagio"></input>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para pegar os valores de cada `input hidden` informado na pergunta, você pode usar o seguinte código na sua função:

```
// esta linha já possui no seu código. OK!
var linSel = $("input[name=listaIndice]:checked").val();

// nesta linha eu seleciono a célula TD onde estão todos os inputs
// e atribuo a uma variável "elementos"
var elementos = $("input[value="+linSel+"][type=radio]").closest("td");

// nesta linha eu uso a variável "elementos" para pegar os valores
// dos inputs pelo nome. Para pegar os valores que quiser, basta
// criar uma nova linha igual e substituir o name= pelo nome do input
// que quer pegar
var idEstagio = elementos.find("input[name=listanuEstagio]").val();
```

Como seu código possui muitos erros, este exemplo abaixo servirá para mostrar como funciona. Execute, marque o `radio` e clique em <kbd>Listar</kbd> para ver o valor do campo `listanuEstagio`:

```js
function listar(){
   var validado = true;
//   if(!checkRadio()){
//      mensagemAlerta("Selecione uma das opções na lista.", "INF");
//      validado = false;
//   }
   if(validado){
var linSel = $("input[name=listaIndice]:checked").val();
var elementos = $("input[value="+linSel+"][type=radio]").closest("td");
var idEstagio = elementos.find("input[name=listanuEstagio]").val();

//        document.getElementById("selEstagioCont").value = idEstagio;

//        var noEstagio = $("input[name=listanoEstagioCont]").val();
//        document.getElementById("noSelEstagioCont").value = noEstagio;

      alert(idEstagio);
//        submitForm("listarContratoDevolucao");
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="modalPane" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
<div id="container">
   <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="corpo">
      <div class="confidencialidade"></div>

      <!-- corpo -->

      <div id="funcao"></div>
      <div class="divisor"></div>
      <div style="float:left;float:right;"></div>

      <form id="form" action="/projet/programa.do" method="post" name="ContratoForm">

         <input id="breadCrumb" type="hidden" value="/projeto/programa.do?.....?mt=pesquisar;" name="breadCrumb">
         <input id="backPage" type="hidden" value="/projeto/programa.do?mt=ini" name="backPage">
         <input id="mt" type="hidden" value="pesquisar" name="mt">
         <input id="nuContrato" type="hidden" value="9999999" name="nuContrato"><input id="chkFiltroNumCont" type="hidden" value="" name="chkFiltroNumContr">
         <input id="tela" type="hidden" value="lista" name="tela"><div id="conteudo"><div class="informacao">

         CNPJ:  

         <b></b>
   </div>
   <div class="informacao">

      Nome Contratante:  

      <b></b>
   </div>
   <div class="grupoLista">
      <script type="text/javascript"></script>
      <input id="qtdTotalLista" type="hidden" value="31" name="qtdTotalLista">
      <div id="divIE" class="divlinhaTabela">
         <table id="tblIE" class="dados" width="100%">
            <tbody style="border: 1px solid #000;">
               <tr class="azul">
                  <th></th>
                  <th nowrap="nowrap"></th>
                  <th nowrap="nowrap"></th>
                  <th nowrap="nowrap"></th>
                  <th nowrap="nowrap"></th>
                  <th nowrap="nowrap"></th>
                  <th nowrap="nowrap"></th>
                  <th nowrap="nowrap"></th>
                  <th nowrap="nowrap" style="text-align:right"></th>
                  <th nowrap="nowrap" style="text-align:right"></th>
                  <th nowrap="nowrap" style="text-align:right"></th>
               </tr>
               <tr class="branco">
                  <td>
                     <input type="radio" value="0" name="listaIndice">
                     <input type="hidden" value="9999999" name="listanuOperacao">
                     <input type="hidden" value="4" name="listanuSituacao">
                     <input type="hidden" value="Contratada/Notificado" name="listanoSituacao">
                     <input type="hidden" value="Contrantante" name="listanoContratado">
                     <input type="hidden" value="Gestor" name="listanoGestor">
                     <input type="hidden" value="19/02/2016" name="listadtAssina">
                     <input type="hidden" value="0000000000010000.00" name="listaValor">
                     <input type="hidden" value="0000000000000000.00" name="listavlDev">
                     <input type="hidden" value="0000000000000000.00" name="listavlCredito">
                     <input type="hidden" value="4" name="listanuEstagio" />
                     <input type="hidden" value="Notificado de TCE" name="listanoEstagioOper"></td>
                  <td nowrap="nowrap"></td>
                  <td nowrap="nowrap"></td>
                  <td nowrap="nowrap">
                     9999999 - 99
                  </td>
                  <td nowrap="nowrap">
                     Contratada/Notificado
                  </td>
                  <td nowrap="nowrap"></td>
                  <td nowrap="nowrap"></td>
                  <td nowrap="nowrap">
                     Contratante
                  </td>
                  <td nowrap="nowrap"></td>
                  <td nowrap="nowrap"></td>
                  <td nowrap="nowrap" style="text-align:right"></td>
                  <td nowrap="nowrap" style="text-align:right"></td>
                  <td nowrap="nowrap" style="text-align:right"></td>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
      <div class="paginacao">
         <div class="numeros"></div>
         <div style="float:left;"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="total"></span>
      <div class="grupoBotaoLista">
         <div class="divisor"></div>

            <img class="botao" onclick="listar();" src="resources/_images/botoes/bt_listar.gif" alt="">
            <img class="botao" onclick="volta();" src="resources/_images/botoes/bt_voltar.gif" alt="">
         </div>
      </div><br />
   </div>
</form>

<!-- mensagem -->
</div>
<div id="rodape"></div></div>
<form id="idsp" method="post" action="#"></form>
<input type="button" value="listar" onclick="listar()" />
```

Comment: obrigada pela ajuda, também consegui com o comando : document.getElementById("nuEstagio").value = document.getElementsByName("listanuEstagio")[linSel].value;

Answer (score 1):

Adiciona class nos inputs:

```
  <input type="radio" class="listaIndice"    name="listaIndice"          value="${idxLinha}" />
  <input type="hidden" class="listanuContrato"   name="listanuContrato"      value="${lista.nuContrato}" />
  <input type="hidden" class="listanuStatus"   name="listanuStatus"        value="${lista.nuStatus}" />
  <input type="hidden" class="listanoStatus"   name="listanoStatus"        value="${lista.noStatus}"/>
  <input type="hidden" class="listanoEmpresa"   name="listanoEmpresa"       value="${lista.noEmpresa}"/>
  <input type="hidden" class="listanoGestor"   name="listanoGestor"        value="${lista.noGestor}"/>
  <input type="hidden" class="listadtAssina"   name="listadtAssina"        value="${lista.dtAssina}"/>
  <input type="hidden" class="listavlContrato"   name="listavlContrato"      value="${lista.vlContrato}"/>
  <input type="hidden" class="listavlDevolucao"   name="listavlDevolucao"     value="${lista.vlDevolucao}"/>
  <input type="hidden" class="listavlDev"   name="listavlDev"   value="${lista.vlDev}"/>
  <input type="hidden" class="listanuEstagio"   name="listanuEstagio"       value="${lista.nuEstagio}"/>
  <input type="hidden" class="listanoEstagioCont"   name="listanoEstagioCont"   value="${lista.noEstagio}"/>
```

no javascript:

```
function listar(){
var validado = true;
if(!checkRadio()){
    mensagemAlerta("Selecione uma das opções na lista.", "INF");
    validado = false;
}
if(validado){
    var linSel = $("input[name=listaIndice]:checked").closest("tr");

    document.getElementById("nuContrato").value = linSel.find('.listanuContrato').val();

    // restantes vars

    submitForm("listarContratoDevolucao");
}
}
```